# Can workfront api join objects?

Tags: workfront-api

Can workfront api (currently I'm using python) join the project object with the company object and the task object through the api?

I am attempting to replicate a spotfire report that includes project, task, and company data.

When I download the project data either through the api (with python) or using https there are no fields in the data that can be used to reference the custid (company) or any task fields.

Is there some connection through the project id field?

Your assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for values that you can use to join two queries, yes it's possible. The exact field will vary based on the objects that you're referencing, but fields like custid and projectID (for tasks) will allow you to make associations. By default, an object query will return a limited set of fields. I suggest adding fields=* to your query to get all possible fields, or provide a comma-seperated list of the fields that you want. You can consult the [API guide](https://developers.workfront.com/api-docs/api-explorer/) for a full list of fields for each object type.